# Return statement should not contain assignment in javascript using filter function

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

I am using following snippet

```js
const country = '';
const countryCodes = ['SE', 'NL', 'SE', 'FR'];
countryCodes.filter((countryCode, index) => {
  country += countryCodes.indexOf(countryCode) === index ? `'${countryCode}'` : '';
});
```

What I am trying is to have following to assign the unique values to country. so country will have following values `SENLFR`
But I got eslint error:

> error  Return statement should not contain assignment
> no-return-assign

I am aware about that filter need to meet both true and false conditions, which I think it is met in my enhanced if statement. But I don't know what is missing

Comment: You're not actually returning anything.

Comment: show countryCodes

Comment: What is `country` and why do you constantly change it and return its value? Performing side effects in filter is certainly an anti pattern.

Comment: @danh That's not the case if there are duplicates.

Comment: @WiatroBosy countryCodes = ['SE', 'NL', 'SE', 'FR']

Comment: Use a regular for loop, this is not an application for filter.

Comment: I attempted to edit to add clarity with some formatting and a working snippet but there appear to be some challenges to that still

Comment: Is it your desire to garner those stated results or to simply better understand the `.filter()` functionality?

Comment: FWIW  "filter need to meet both true and false condition" is not strictly true since filter creates a shallow copy of the original given a condition that returns true for each desired value.  SO you need to capture that shallow copy for a `true`  condition for each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If trying to remove dups, use a set, which rejects duplicates, then spread it back into an array...

```js
const countryCodes = ['SE', 'NL', 'SE', 'FR']
const result = [...new Set(countryCodes)]
console.log(result)

// concatenated...
console.log(result.join(''))
```